# determining the distribution of Y

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a little doubt regarding this exercise
3 batteries (X1,X2,X3) are connected to a lightbulb Y. The battery lifetimes are iid exponetial distribuited such that E(X) = $\lambda$
Our experiment to measure the lifetime of the light bulb is stopped when any one of the batteries fails. Hence,the only random variable we observe is $Y=min(X1,X2,X3)$.
Since they are I.I.D the distribution of Y should be the product of $f(x1) f(x2) f(x3)$

so I got $\frac{1}{\lambda}^{3}$ $exp^{\frac{-3x}{\lambda}}$
Am I correct?

Comment: No. The distribution of $Y$ is not the product. The joint distribution of the vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is the product $f(x_1)f(x_2)f(x_3)$, but this is not the distribution of $Y$ (since it's the distribution of a random vector, not a random variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should compute the distribution of $Y$ from first principles.

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leqslant t) = 1-\mathbb{P}(Y>t)=1-\mathbb{P}((\forall i)(X_i>t)) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_1>t)^3=1-e^{-3t/\lambda}.$$ Here we have used that the minimum is greater than $t$ if and only if each of $X_1, X_2, X_3$ is greater than $t$. We have also used that the random variables are independent and identically distributed to split the probability $\mathbb{P}((\forall i)(X_i>t))=\mathbb{P}(X_1>t)^3$.

We can now differentiate $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{P}(Y\leqslant t)$ to get the pdf $e^{-3t/\lambda}/(\lambda/3)$, which is exponential with mean $\lambda/3$.

Comment: thank you very much! so the maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$ would be $\lambda_{MLE} =3\times\bar T $

Comment: Or would the mle be $\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}$?

Comment: If we want an MLE in terms of the minimum, it is $3\min\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$.  This is because the log likelihood for the minimum is $$\ell(\lambda;T)=\log[e^{-3T/\lambda}/(\lambda/3)]=-\frac{3T}{\lambda}-\log(\lambda)+\log(3).$$ Differentiating gives $3T/\lambda^2-1/\lambda$. Set equal to zero, multiply by $\lambda^2$, and add $\lambda$ to get $\hat{\lambda}=3T$. This is if we want to use the observed value of the minimum, as opposed to the entire sample $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$.

Comment: in this case you don't consider the joint likelihood and go directly to the loglikelihood from the pdf? why?

Comment: There can be two contexts: If we know all three values $X_1, X_2, X_3$, we would use the joint likelihood. If we don't know all three values $X_1, X_2, X_3$, but only know the minimum (which is what it sounds like in this problem, since the first part asks about the minimum), then we can't use the joint likelihood, which requires the three individual values.

Comment: For example, we could consider electrical components in series, where the series fails when the first component fails. It could be specified in the problem that we know the series failed at $3.5$ seconds, so we know $\min (X_1,X_2,X_3)=3.5$. But we don't know $X_1, X_2$, and $X_3$, which would be required to obtain the MLE from the joint pdf.

As a rule of thumb, more information is better (or, at the very least, not worse*). So if we had enough data to do it both ways, we'd use the method that uses the full data.

Comment: *Here we run into the notion of sufficient statistics. In this case, if we know $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ and the mean $\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^3 X_i$, the latter actually contains all of the *useful* information from the sample, so using the mean is *equivalent* to using the full sample in this case.

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct. Note that the pdf in your result does not integrate to one over the suitable interval, so it cannot be the solution. You can get the correct solution as follows. Define $Y$ as you did. First, define the rate $\mu = 1/ \lambda$. Then,

$$
F_Y(x) = P(Y \leq x) = 1 - P(Y > x) = 1 - P(X_i > x \hspace{0.1cm}\forall i) = 1 - \prod_{i = 1}^3 P(X_i > x) = 1 - \prod_{i = 1}^3 e^{-\mu x} = 1-\exp(-3\mu x).
$$
Hence $Y$ has an exponential distribution with rate $3\mu$. Hence, $EY = \lambda / 3$.

Comment: That's not correct. The mean of the minimum shouldn't be greater than the mean of the $X_i$. It should be less.

Comment: The cdf of an exponential with mean $\lambda$ is $1-e^{-x/\lambda}$, not $1-e^{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: Right, I parametrized it with the rate.